# My boolean always comes up correct

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

In my following piece of code I am looking to compare a piece of a text file.
However, for some reason, no matter what the user types in the value comes up
correct.

I'm trying to compare the value without worrying about its case or about any
leading or trailing white space.

```
// Display the question to the user
System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random1));

// Accept user input
System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");

// Store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
System.out.println();

// Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
System.out.println("Answer: " + myList.get(random1 +1));

// if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
// correct and award points
// else tell them they suck LOL
if(myList.get(random1 + 1).contains(answer) == false) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
    System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
}
else {
    System.out.println("You suckkkkkkk");
}

// Display total accumulated points
System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);

// Wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
System.out.print("Hit Enter");
scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Advice: don't use `myList.get(random1 +1).contains(answer) == false`, use `!myList.get(random1 +1).contains(answer)`

Comment: How is myList defined? What is random1?

Comment: If the official answer does NOT contain the entered answer, that is considered to be correct?

Comment: @ScottHunter Ooh, good eyes!

Comment: Most people here complain when things are *not* correct.

Comment: Have you checked to see what is actually stored in answer?

Comment: Yes, in my text file I have the answers. But as i answer them I have no other result then correct

Comment: A good start would be `if(myList.get(random1 +1).contains(answer) == true`

Comment: Try `String rightAnswer = myList.get(random1 +1); if(rightAnswer.equals(answer) ....` see if it works well @StevenEck

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized; the code in the question checks that a condition is false, rather than that it is true.  The question & answer are unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
// Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
String correctAnswer =  myList.get(random1 +1); 
System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer); // Instead use a variable

// if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
// correct and award points
// else tell them they suck LOL
if(correctAnswer.equalIgnoreCase(answer)) { // efficient than contains() method
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
    System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
}
else {
    System.out.println("You suckkkkkkk");
}
```