# rmi remote exception. RMI doesnt work

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I get a remote exception when I try to run my RMI example. I cannot understand why.
I run the program without any arguments to the program itself or to the JVM.

Please help me to get rid of the exception.

Thanks very much

This is the exception I get:

```
Server exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.Hello
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.Hello
```

These are the classes I have:

The client class:

```
package hello;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
        String response = stub.sayHello();
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

The remote interace:

```
package hello;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

And finally the server:

```
package hello;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Server obj = new Server();
        Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
        registry.bind("Hello", stub);

        System.err.println("Server ready");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is likely that the client can't find the interface.  Both the client and server are required to have the copy of interface and prior to Java 6, you would also need to use rmic to build a client stubby

Comment: Have you tried using [Spring-Remoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017734/my-boolean-always-comes-up-correct/19017859#19017859). That would make RMI very easy.

Comment: You're doing `getRegistry(null)` when you send no argument. Also, Which OS are you using? If you're in Ubuntu, `127.0.1.1:1099` is the host address.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for clearing it out. While I started doing RMI, I was stuck with using `127.0.0.1`. :/

Answer (score 1):

Either the Registry or the client or both cannot find the class named in the exception. There are several possible solutions:

1. include that class in the classpath when executing the Registry and the client. And all the classes it depends on, recursively until closure.
2. Start the Registry from inside the server JVM, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, which solves that classpath problem, and provide the necessary classes on the client's classpath only.
3. Use the codebase feature to ensure all the system components can access the required server-side classes.

Answer (score -1):

As outlined in the [RMI trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/)

You may need to supply the `java.rmi.server.codebase` parameter that list all the jars that the RMI server needs to export the objects...

See [Running the examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html) and look at the "Starting the server" section.  Also be sure to check out the section on running the client program for additional suggested parameters

Comment: This is only one of the possible solutions. He doesn't 'need' to do this at all.

Comment: @EJP Really, because it was the only way I could get it to work

Comment: Yes really. It is not the only way it can work. See my answer.

Comment: `Solution 1` didn't seem to work for me while test. Is the classpath contextual to the RMIRegistry itself?

Comment: @EJP It would seem to be "preferred" solution if you were attempting to deploy multiple solutions through a single registry, but then again, you might consider using multiple registries...just thinking out loud ;) - And as you say, this is "A" solution ;)

Comment: If Solution 1 didn't work for you, you didn't do it right. You need to start the RMIRegistry with a `-J-classpath=...` argument, or else, much better, start it inside the server JVM with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(),` whereupon it uses the same classpath as the server JVM. The codebase feature is a deployment option, and sometimes a very useful one, but never a requirement, or even a 'preference'.

Comment: @EJP Hm, nice to know. While my RMI experience is pretty slim, I can still a need for the code base in situations where you don't have control over the server itself, per-say.  Thanks for the info though...It's also interesting that you say it's not "preference", given that all the documentation I've read on the subject uses this mechanism - in particular for it's dynamic class loading functionality since 1.6...

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't a *use* for the codebase feature. I said it is neither 'needed', 'preferred', 'required', etc. Dynamic class loading via the codebase feature has been there since 1.1, not 1.6. You can mention all the documentation you like but will be unable to produce a Sun or Oracle reference that says it is needed, required, preferred, etc. Nor is it 'needed' in the OP's situation.

Comment: @EJP Relax, I'm digging for information to try and learn something, not to prove a point ;) - I could quite as easily argue that the classpath for the register is not need, required, prefered or otherwise, it's about the required context at the time ;)

Comment: @EJP As I understand the architecture, it was a requirement to distribute the stubbies, generated by the rmic prior to 1.6, it was 1.6 which did away with this - as I understand (otherwise we've being making our lives more difficult for the last 3 years :P)

Comment: More misinformation, and more fallacious reasoning. (1) Setting the classpath for the Registry was presented as one of several solutions: not as something that is 'needed', unlike your own answer. Nobody has said it was 'needed', so no counterargument is required. (2) Dynamic stubs started in 1.5, not 1.6.